# CiviMail broken after upgrade from 4.7.20 to 4.7.27 (Drupal 7.56)

Tags: civimail

When I click Mailing > New Mailing, I get the following URL :
https://mysite.com/civicrm/a/#/mailing/new, (instead of
https://mysite.com/civicrm/mailing/new ?)
... and I am driven to a dashboard page

When I select a Group and want to send a mailing, the same happens

Any help is welcome

Comment: Sounds like angular is not loading. Can you double check your Resource and Directory path settings.

Comment: I just upgraded to 4.7.27 on Drupal and I do not have this problem. It sounds like you may need to check your resource paths as Peterdnz suggested, as well as delete everything inside the `sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates_c` folder and run then clear your CiviCRM caches. It's worth mentioning that you should also clear your browser cache.

Comment: Thank you Pete and Christia ; checking Resource and Directory paths fixed the problem ... but I don't understand how the problem happened. Pete, if you transform your observation into an answer, I will quote it as such.